# Calling a rails controller method with jQuery on "beforeunload"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'd like to call a method in my controller when a user leaves a page. Ideally I'd also like to pass in a couple of parameters.

This is what I've got. Not sure if I'm handing the parameter properly and my leave method is never called.

#### In 'show.html.erb'

```
<script language="javascript"> 
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    $.get('/leave?foo='+<%= @bar %>, null, null, null)
    });
</script>
```

#### In 'routes.rb'

`match '/leave' to: 'posts#leave'`

#### In 'posts_controller.rb'

```
def leave
  puts params[:bar]
end
```

Note: putting a `link_to` directly to `/leave` works fine and replace the jQuery `$.get` with `return true;` throws a dialog when the user tries to leave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using unobstrusive JS. In one of my Coffeescript files I put:

```
jQuery ->
  $(window).on('beforeunload', ->
    $.get('/leave?foo=bar', null)
    return "Bye!")
```

I'd like to do this without the alert, but unless I return something, GET doesn't work. Weird, but it's a separate question.

Thanks for your help, Mark.

Answer (score 2):

Very close. Assuming your parameter is something like:

```
foo=bar
```

Your jQuery get becomes:

```
$.get('/leave?foo=bar', null, null, null)
```

Does your route not throw a syntax error (sorry, Rails changes routing with every major release, so perhaps this works on Rails 2.x but it doesn't on 3.x). Instead of:

```
match '/leave' to: 'posts#leave'
```

use...

```
match '/leave' => 'posts#leave'
```

In your controller:

```
def leave
  puts params[:foo]
end
```

Or, if you just want to test for the existence of the parameter:

```
def leave
  puts params.include?(:foo)
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make my question very clear. My `leave` method isn't getting called at all. I can put a `link_to` to `/leave` and everything works fine, but `$.get('/leave',...` does nothing, and nothing is logged. (Replace $.get... with `return true;` throws a dialog when the user leaves, so it must be bound correctly.)

Comment: I've edited my answer to suggest a different route. I also notice that you edited your question so that my answers on both the Javascript side and Rails side to your parameter passing problem are no longer needed.